# Pull Data off of Remote Server into Local Server ... Best, Most Secure Way 

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a online signup that saves data onto a hosted mssql database ... Essentially what i'm trying to do is as have a daily routine run on the local server as simple as

```
Insert into Home.tableA Select * from Remote.tableA Where Date = Today
```

However, this will not work ... what would be the best way to accomplish this either in T-SQL or C# ...

Thanks for the Insight

Comment: Is SQL Server Replication an option?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not, My initial though was to do a C# console app with a data-table that is populated from the remote server and then inserts into the home server but it is rather inelegant

Comment: -you can do a backup job in a daily basis for remote database and a restore job (always daily) in the local server.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear ... it either needs to run as a sql agent job or a scripted job ... The remote is on a hosted (winhost) web-server that I have no access to other then a connection string ...

Comment: -well.. if you can't administer remote sql-server the backup solution didnt  help. You can always populate a dataset after a select on remote server an then create a table on local sql-server (create or update table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option 1. You can setup table replication

option 2. You can get Home.TableA Max(Id) and insert rows from Remote.TableA where Remote.TableA.ID > Home.TableA Max(Id).

option 3. Setup another table to keep the MAX(Id) and datetime the job run.